# Fried Beaglebone Black - Possible Reasons?

Tags: power-supply

I've fried my beaglebone while powering it from a switching regulator which gives around 4.95V , The output voltage of the regulator was pretty stable with low ripple voltage. What happened was it all started good and it was starting up , all of a sudden after 15-20 second the beaglebone turned off and it doesn't work anymore.

Here is the relevant connection I suspect which might caused the problem . I use it to monitor the error signal from another voltage regulator (The error flag output, (or power OK) is the collector of a NPN transistor, with the emitter internally grounded) .

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFay0G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also as I found in beaglebone documentation, it is stated that no pin shall be driven before the SYS_RESET line goes high , can this have anything to do with this ? I have a spare one but I don't want to risk it before I find the problem.

Addition from the datasheet:

Error Flag (Pin 3)Open collector output that provides a low signal (flag transistor ON) when the regulated output
voltage drops more than 5% from the nominal output voltage. On start up, Error Flag is low until VOUT
reaches 95% of the nominal output voltage.

[image]

Comment: I believe that the source of your problem comes from the error signal connection.  I need a diagram of the circuitry of the error signal and the beaglebone input to be able to figure out the problem.

Comment: I've added the diagram of the circuit in the main post. So the error flag is connected directly to the beaglebone input. However I'm not sure if this is causing the problem, I'm just suspected because I'm not really sure.

Comment: From looking at the error flag circuitry, there is no way it can cause the problem.  The worst it can do, is maintain the error flag at ground, unless somehow the transistor collector is shorted to Vin.

Comment: Now I need to look at the circuitry feeding the 3.3v.

Comment: Thanks, I guess there was another problem , I might have to check the other circuitry thoroughly.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the power feeding the 3.3v is not isolated, there could be a path from the AC line to the input of the beaglebone and that would "fry it" no time.  Good luck.